# Do Arrays function the same way in Go as they do in Ruby or Python?

Tags: arrays, go

In Ruby an array can hold a string or an integer, the same seems true in Javascript and python. But in Go, putting integers and strings together seems difficult, or at least i couldn't figure it out. Is an array able to take both integers and strings within Go in the same way that Python and Ruby can?

Ruby:

```
a = [20, "tim"]
puts a
```

Python:

```
a = [20, "tim"]
print(a)
```

Go:

```
?
```

Comment: Yeah, they aren't the same; they're typed. You can explicitly make a `[]interface{}` but I honestly don't see that many places (though it's in some important spots like the signature of `fmt.Println` and similar functions I guess). You probably want to check out https://tour.golang.org/ to get started with Go.

Comment: What do you mean by typed? You mean they type (40) int ("name") string right? I did but i am pretty new to programming so it's definitely confusing.

Comment: Yeah, that kind of type. Do [the tour](https://tour.golang.org/) or find Go or introductory programming materials, though--StackOverflow isn't structured to be a good way to learn programming.

Comment: They're similar enough that `a = [20, "tim]` is a syntax error in all three languages.

Answer (score 1):

Because Go is a typed language, to create a slice of multiple types in Go, you need to specify a type that multiple types can satisfy. To do this in Go, create a slice of the empty interface (`interface{}`) such as the following:

```
a := []interface{}{20, "tim"}
fmt.Println(a)
```

This works because the empty interface is an interface with no methods so all types will match it.

Creating a slice or array of mixed types isn't generally done in Go but this is the way to do it if you need it.

You can read more about interfaces here:

- [Jordan Orelli's How to use interfaces in Go](http://jordanorelli.com/post/32665860244/how-to-use-interfaces-in-go)
- [Go Language Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)
- [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types)

Comment: Thanks. Will checkout interfaces. I see learning Go makes me look much deeper into programming concepts than with Python and it's definitely more difficult at first.

Comment: Might also suggest the tour, or some general introduction to static vs. dynamic typing (but I don't know where a good one is).

Comment: Click on the Go tag, then click on the "info" tab for a great list of Golang resources.